# How can I prevent my HBars from overlapping in Bokeh?

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I have 'categorical data' groups of things that have run for a period of time. Some of these things also ran concurrently. I wanted to display these categories on a timeline in Bokeh Python.

However, the original attempt wasn't successful: 
[image]

After that, I tried to jitter them, but it created something quite messy and unstructured (probably the point of jitter and I'm just not using it correctly.) 
[image]

Ideally, I would just like a method that allows me to stagger these items within each category, but I am not sure how.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to jitter, you want to visually dodge, which is [demonstrated in the documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#visual-dodge).

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=fruits, y_range=(0, 10), plot_height=250)
p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits', -0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2015', width=0.2, source=source, color="#c9d9d3")
p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.0,  range=p.x_range), top='2016', width=0.2, source=source, color="#718dbf")
p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2017', width=0.2, source=source, color="#e84d60")

p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

[image]

Alteratively, you might use explicit [Categorical Offsets](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-offsets):

```
fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']

offsets = [-0.5, -0.2, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3]

# This results in [ ['Apples', -0.5], ['Pears', -0.2], ... ]
x = list(zip(fruits, offsets))

p.vbar(x=x, top=[5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6], width=0.8)
```

[image]